# Running Spring cloud (Zuul, Eureka and 2 rest backend service) with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, nginx-ingress

I have a microservices architecture with Docker containers and now want to move to deploy using Kubernetes. 
I am not able to run the application with Kubernetes. The gateway server is not connecting to service discovery and forwarding request.

As a demo application I have created 4 services:
- Zuul service
- Eureka service
- Contact service
- User service

Githube repo - https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservice-k8s

The application runs fine with docker-compose. I have created the images and pushed to Dockerhub.

K8s files - https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservice-k8s/tree/master/k8s

To forward request I have setup Ingress-nginx.

I started the service by running follwoing:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
```

then

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Ingress-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: zuul-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8050
```

The request goes to zuul but following errors comes in logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: contactus-5448dd4d9c-5gj5r
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
    ... 127 common frames omitted
```

If I set eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true I get the following exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at or
```

This is probably because services must have registered via pods name. How to handle such situations so that each downstream service registers via its cluster-IP?

Comment: The eureka-service name is eureka-cluster-ip-service, but in your deployments, it uses eureka:8761. Try changing eureka service name to eureka

Comment: Thanks for the catch. The services gets registers now.

Comment: Can you help me with the forwarding of the request to the Zuul service?

Comment: you don't need to register clusterIP to eureka. I think you are almost there, if i were you, i would check the register infos, and handly test by curl in the containers. both zuul and your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a.l. pointed out that the SPRING_EUREKA value should be the cluster-ip:

```
value: http://eureka-cluster-ip-service:8761/eureka
```

Also, all service preferIpAddress should be true:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```